# Android Studio string hello_world not present in string.xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android app development, trying to follow an intro book on the subject. After creating a blank project, I'm instructed to open the **string.xml** file, which is supposed to contained the element `<string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>` in order to edit the default text of the TextView object. However, the file doesn't contain this element. It only contains:

[image]

Also, the book only shows an `activity_main.xml` layout file, whereas I'm seeing both an `activity_main.xml` and a `content_main.xml` file.

Perhaps this is a version issue? My install of the Android SDK is on Windows 10 with the latest API 23, whereas I think the book was published before API 23 was released.

Comment: "in order to edit the default text of the TextView object" -- there may not even *be* a `TextView` object, depending on what template you used when creating the project. Any book older than six months is likely to be out of sync in spots with how Android Studio behaves.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Is there a way I can uninstall SDK 23 so I can be in sync with the book?

Comment: Your problem is not "SDK 23". Your problem is that Android Studio changes, including the templates used for creating new projects and activities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default project template has probably changed since the book was written.

Try creating a new project, and when asked, choose "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity". This should only include `activity_main.xml`

This doesn't include the `hello_world` string in the resources however, so just add it yourself by adding a line with

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
```

to the `strings.xml`

Moreover, they decided to break the convention they had been going with for the default template. There is a `TextView` in the `activity_main.xml` layout, but it uses a hardcoded string, rather than a string resource.

If you modify the `text` attribute of this `TextView` to: `@string/hello_world`, you should be able to mirror the desired behavior that the book is asking for.

Here's a page straight out from the official Android docs on String resources. It may help you understand it better: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Yes, but if he does this, "Hello World!" won't show up in his application because it isn't called in the current template he has. If you tell him to add that line, you might as well tell him to add a corresponding TextView, plus some java code that makes use of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But I'm curious: If the <code>hello_world</code> isn't in the string.xml file, what is generating the "Hello World!" text in the TextView object?

Comment: You are allowed to set `TextView` text with a string directly in the `xml`, but it'll usually give you a warning to set it from a String resource instead. They used to include this with the basic template, but have since changed it. Check my edited answer, it should help you out more